# Auto complete not working Liferay 6.2

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, liferay, liferay-aui

I have followed  http://www.liferaysavvy.com/2014/02/liferay-aui-auto-complete-list.html for auto complete, I am getting data from the server in the following format (in the code:

```
 alert('jsonArray came: ' + jsonArray))
```

gives following,

```
   [
    {
        "roleName": "Organization User",
        "roleId": 10147
    },
    {
        "roleName": "Site Admin",
        "roleId": 16883
    },
    {
        "roleName": "Student",
        "roleId": 18139
    },
    {
        "roleName": "Parent",
        "roleId": 18146
    },
    {
        "roleName": "Faculty",
        "roleId": 18153
    },
    {
        "roleName": "SchooloneStudent",
        "roleId": 27701
    }
]
```

, but from the code:     new A.AutoCompleteList it is not able get data. can any one help me?

```
<aui:script>
AUI().use('autocomplete-list','aui-base','aui-io-request','autocomplete-filters','autocomplete-highlighters',function (A) {
A.io.request('<%=getRoles%>',{
dataType: 'json',
method: 'GET',
on: {
success: function(event, id, obj) {

var instance = this ;
var data = instance.get('responseData');
var jsonArray = JSON.stringify(data);
alert('result came: ' + data);
alert('jsonArray came: ' + jsonArray);
try {
new A.AutoCompleteList(
{
allowBrowserAutocomplete: 'false',
activateFirstItem: 'true',
inputNode: '#<portlet:namespace />ListOfRoles',
resultTextLocator: 'roleName',
render: 'true',
resultHighlighter: 'phraseMatch',
resultFilters:['phraseMatch'],
source:jsonArray,
});
}catch(e) {
alert('not working : ' + e);
}
}

}
});

});
</aui:script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you no need to signify the response as you are already getting response in JSON format. There might be some data mismatch...
Try this:

```
<aui:script>
AUI().use('autocomplete-list','aui-base','aui-io-request','autocomplete-filters','autocomplete-highlighters',function (A) {
A.io.request('<%=getRoles%>',{
            dataType: 'json',
            method: 'GET',
            on: {
                success: function(event, id, obj) {

                    try {
                    new A.AutoCompleteList(
                            {
                            allowBrowserAutocomplete: 'false',
                            activateFirstItem: 'true',
                            inputNode: '#<portlet:namespace />roleNames',
                            resultTextLocator: 'roleName',
                            render: 'true',
                            resultHighlighter: 'phraseMatch',
                            resultFilters:['phraseMatch'],
                            source:this.get('responseData'),
                            autoLoad:false,
                            sync:false,
                            });
                        }catch(e) {
                        alert('not working: ' + e);
                    }
                }

                }
            });

});
</aui:script>
```

Thanks,

~Chandan